# The right way to output an error message from a Python library

Tags: python, logging, stderr

I now have in my Python code:

```
sys.stderr.write("Iteration stopped to avoid infinite loop.\n")
```

but this code always writes to stderr no matter what the client of the code wants.

I would use a logger instead, but that would output to stderr a message like:

```
:INFO:main:Iteration stopped to avoid infinite loop.
```

instead of

```
Iteration stopped to avoid infinite loop.
```

I do not want `:INFO:main:` for this particular message.

So my questions:

- Can I configure a logger to not output `:INFO:main:`?
- What else except Python logger can I use?

If there is no such class in Python installations, then what should be the interface of my own logger class? Should it be like

```
class MyLogger(object):
    @abstractmethod
    def log(msg):
        pass
```

or what may I miss (maybe add some other methods, maybe some additional `log()` arguments)?

Comment: Did you look into logging's configuration at all? You can set up whatever template you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `basicConfig` to change the error message

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s')
logging.warning("Iteration stopped to avoid infinite loop.")
```